# Make query on null field Appengine search document?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In a appengine search document, can I make a request on only null value something like ?

```
myfield = ""
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/)  and i don't found how to make this kind of request.

Do you have any suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with a field fieldNull who takes a boolean true or false and i make a query

```
fieldNull = true
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to filter for missing/Null values of fields in appengine searches.
Only hacks like the one suggested byLionel, would be way to settle with.